# Using Java & .NET in Projects Development

Tags: java, .net, project-management, project

I'm writing this topic for learning purpose, not to start a flame war.

Basing on your experiences when It's highly recommended to use `Java` and not `.NET`, and when I must use `.NET` and not `Java`, also when I have the choice to use anyone of them in `Projects development`.

Thanks already.

Comment: It's a choice of lesser evils, I suppose, and then further, better the devil you know.

Answer (score 4):

The choice of language always depends on what you and your team know best and the problem at hand.

It's not common to do scientific computing with heavy numerical methods in Ruby or PHP; no one writes web apps in FORTRAN.  The problem you're solving will affect the choice.

Your deployment environment will also affect the .NET versus Java EE choice.  If you're a 100% Microsoft shop, .NET is an easy choice.  If you have a heterogeneous environment, maybe Java EE is for you.  If you like Linux, perhaps Java EE is preferred over Mono.

.NET and Java EE have evolved to solve similar kinds of problems.  There's almost a 1:1 correspondence between features in the language, except for some advances like closures that .NET has added.